# Merging scripting related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

It looks like there is no difference between [shell-scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting), [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/script) and [scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scripts) tag. Should we merge those and add tag synonym from script to scripts or vice versa?

Comment: plurals are almost always safe merge/synonyms

Comment: @Jeff, yes, but unfortunately I can't do that (as far as I know)

Comment: And well, there is also shell-scripting, which looks like being ~same, at least it's not used consistently for something else.

Comment: [Unix.SE inconsistently uses `shell` + `script` or `shell-scripting`](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347/on-the-shell-shell-script-command-line-and-terminal-tags).

Answer (score 4):

Huh, very good find.

I think they should all be synonyms of [scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scripting), which doesn't even exist at the moment. Anyone agree? :)

Answer (score 3):

Completed.

Thank you for your attention to detail. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  I don't really think of shell-scripting and scripting as the same thing.  Shell scripting is a sub-category, but it is a well-known sub-category with a long history and independent existence.  "Scripting" by itself is a generic -- it's light programming that might be done with shell syntax/semantics, but it could be done with expect, sed, awk , a little perl, maybe some tcl/tk.

To me, shell-scripting actually makes more sense as a tag, because 'scripting' is so vague as to be nearly meaningless.   It's basically a meta tag that means 'a program written in something other than Java or C (or variants)'.  Tags might as well be more precise rather than less, and just come out and say 'shell scripting,' or 'python,' or 'perl'.